# How do I get value of datetime object in drupal 8?

Tags: datetime, drupal-8

There is a Datetime object as following and I want to get the date value

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime Object
                (
                    [formatTranslationCache:protected] => 
                    [inputTimeRaw:protected] => 
                    [inputTimeAdjusted:protected] => 
                    [inputTimeZoneRaw:protected] => 
                    [inputTimeZoneAdjusted:protected] => 
                    [inputFormatRaw:protected] => 
                    [inputFormatAdjusted:protected] => 
                    [langcode:protected] => en
                    [errors:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [dateTimeObject:protected] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2018-01-05 01:30:00.000000
                            [timezone_type] => 3
                            [timezone] => UTC
                        )

                    [stringTranslation:protected] => 
                )

        )

)
```

I don't want to get this value by

```
$node->get("field_id")->value;
```

Because I need dynamic value that means the value should change after I changed date field.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out

```
$date =  $form_state->getValue('field_id')[0]['value']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

it returns string !!

The point is locate the Object.

Comment: So this returns an object $form_state->getValue('field_id')[0]['value'] who has methods ->format() and ->__toString()

Comment: why doesn't getValue() give you the Drupal DateTime Object... Drupal is so lame.

Comment: It does. getValue() gives you a DrupalDateTime.

Answer (score 0):

The values in the array are of type **Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime**, check the API on Drupal.org [DrupalDateTime Doc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DrupalDateTime.php/class/DrupalDateTime/8.2.x).

In order to get value from the object you must use the **__toString** method as mentioned.

Proceed as :

```
$dateTime = YourArray[0]['value'];
$date = $dateTime->_toString();
```

Else

```
$date = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d h::i::s');
```

For more date formats check the PHP doc [PHP DATE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Edit 1:
The following Code works correctly :

```
$temp = new \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime();
echo $temp->__toString();
echo $temp->format('Y-m-d h::i'); die;
```

Comment: I've tried "$date = $dateTime->_toString();" and "$date = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d h::i::s');" but drupal throwing exceptions:Error: Call to a member function format() on array ...and so on ,it's the same when I'm using "_toString()" method.it seems methods are not exist.

Comment: I've invoked Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime and Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface btw.

Comment: $node->get("field_id"); what does this returns

Comment: The error what PHP is throwing, is the key to your answer. Call to a member function on array, we must call that function from Object. The following function works

Comment: $node->get('field_id')->value; it means get the field value by field id .here it is :$node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity; and then you can use $node->get('field_id')->value to get field value.The value is a string.

Comment: I'm using $date = $form_state->getValue('field_id'); it returns an datetime object as mentioned;

Comment: I've solved the problem and post a solution under my question Thanks for your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found that in browsers that do no support

```
<input type="time">
```

(i.e. Safari) the value is not of type "Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime" but array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did inside a drupal 8 module to get formatted date from [DrupalDateTime](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DrupalDateTime.php/class/DrupalDateTime/8.7.x)

I. If you have a date and want format it, just pass it to the static method of the class (DrupalDateTime) as follows. You can replace the string with your date variables.
Below shows both using the static version and non static version of **DrupalDateTime**

```
 $date = DrupalDateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '20-Jul-2019');
// Using the static method prints out: 20-Jul-2019:11:am

$date = new DrupalDateTime('now');  // grab current dateTime using NON static
$date->format('l, F j, Y - H:i'); // format it 
// prints out nicely formatted version: Tue, Jul 16, 2019 - 11:34:am
// you can remove H:i and what's after it if you don't want hours or am pm

$date = new DrupalDateTime('now');  // grab current dateTime
// Or print $date->format('d-m-Y: H:i A');
// prints out: 16-07-2019: 11:43 AM
```

More examples:

```
$date = new DrupalDateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
print $date->format('m/d/Y g:i a');
// The above prints current time for given Timezone
// prints : 07/16/2019 10:59 am

// Another variations of the above except it takes specific date and UTC zone
$date = new DrupalDateTime('2019-07-31 11:30:00', 'UTC');
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
print $date->format('m/d/Y g:i a');
// prints 07/31/2019 6:30 am
```

To use these in your module/code you need to include the following at the top of your file;

```
 use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;
```

Also **note** that the DrupalDateTime extends [DateTimePlus](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Datetime%21DateTimePlus.php/class/DateTimePlus/8.7.x)() which it self "wraps the PHP DateTime class with more flexible initialization parameters.... as per docs..."

**How to test it with Drush.**
Save the above code in a php script, then let drush run the srcipt after it bootstraps drupal like:

```
drush -r /path-to-your-drupal-documentRoot -l example.com scr ~/path-to your-script
```

For multisites make sure you use ... drush -l http.... like above

Note:
I posted similar answer to: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/252333/how-to-get-formatted-date-string-from-a-datetimeitem-object/283529#283529

Answer (score 0):

in my case I use date range with duration
in your case you need the bold one

**date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime($date->get('field')->getValue()[0]['value']))**

date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime($date->get('field')->getValue()[0]['end_value']))